# Wordpress Responsive Design (height issue)

Tags: wordpress, responsive, display

I'm currently working on creating a page with wordpress,
and I'd like the page to not allow SCROLLING. I want it to be a still-page, that adapts to the width/height of any display.

However, I am not accomplishing this, and my current design attempt keeps showing a lot of whitespace below the content of the page.

Pictured here:
[image]

I know it is possible to have a page that doesn't scroll (on any display size) and fits without any overflow whitespace, but I don't know how to tackle this, can someone point me in the right direction? Any special css approach I should take? (Note, I am using divi as a page building theme)

Here is a site that shows really good example of what I am trying to accomplish in terms of no scrolling, and fitting to display:
[Sally King benedict - Contemporary Artist site](https://sallykingbenedict.com/)

Comment: Can you show what your css looks like? Or maybe provide the link to the page. I would suggest making a gradient background that covers the page and use an image fixed to the bottom right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, and for the sake of sharing knowledge and information, here is how I solved it:

Issue: I wanted the page to be fit to any screen's display (mobile, desktop/laptops of any size, etc). The issue I was having was that the page I created looked decent on my laptop's display, but on larger displays, there was a large amount of whitespace beneath the content itself.

Fix: I made the section min-height of the page 100% vh. That is, the minimum height of the page will be 100% of the viewport height. in css this looks like this:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Now my page is full-screen on every display, and it doesn't overflow with a scroll bar or any whitespace. However, there is a new issue I am facing (and someone with the same issue might face), that is, now the content on the page looks odd as it is all at the top, and not exactly centered. There are some more approaches you can take to make sure that the content follows the center of the display, gone over here:

[CSS tricks - Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

And here is all the css which I am using to make sure the content on the page is centered (with the addition of the previously explained code):

```
min-height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Again, I am using Divi, so I am putting this CSS in the *section* on my page (main element).

Hopefully if anyone has this issue, this will help you out a bit, or at least point you in the right direction.